# How long will a temporary MEMORY table persist if I don't drop it (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables, memory-table

I'm using a recursive stored procedure in MySQL to generate a temporary table called `id_list`, but I must use the results of that procedure in a follow up select query, so I can't `DROP` the temporary table within the procedure...

```
BEGIN;

/* generates the temporary table of ID's */
CALL fetch_inheritance_groups('abc123',0);

/* uses the results of the SPROC in the WHERE */
SELECT a.User_ID
FROM usr_relationships r 
INNER JOIN usr_accts a ON a.User_ID = r.User_ID 
WHERE r.Group_ID = 'abc123' OR r.Group_ID IN (SELECT * FROM id_list) 
GROUP BY r.User_ID;

COMMIT;
```

When calling the procedure, the first value is the top ID of the branch I want, and the second is the `tier` which the procedure uses during recursions. Prior to the recursive loop it checks if `tier = 0` and if it is it runs:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS id_list;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS id_list (iid CHAR(32) NOT NULL) ENGINE=memory;
```

So my question is: **If I don't `DROP` the temporary `MEMORY` table at the end of the procedure, or within my transaction, how long will that table persist in memory?  Is it automatically dropped once the session ends, or will it remain in memory as long as the connection is open?**

**N.B. The obvious answer might be to drop the temp table prior to the commit statement, but lets assume for a moment that I can't do that.*

---

A more detailed answer to this question can be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57971/how-long-will-a-temporary-memory-table-persist-if-i-dont-drop-it-mysql so I've voted to close this question.

Comment: This question was cross posted in the DBA StackExchange and I answered it : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57976/877

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html), the temporary table is dropped automatically when the connection is closed (emphasis mine):

> **Temporary Tables**
>
> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY
>   table is visible only to the current connection, and ***is dropped
>   automatically when the connection is closed***.

Comment: Thank Ike, I asked the same of another response, I'm trying to figure out if it's tied to the connection (which may be persistent across requests) vs the request itself.  From the sounds of the man page you've pointed at, it's the connection, so we would need to explicitly drop the memory table if we employ persistent connections. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend dropping it explicitly if you employ persistent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tables are in the scope of database connection

Comment: So if the system uses persistent connections / caches connections, then the `MEMORY` table would persist as long as that users connection remains active, from REQUEST to REQUEST?

Comment: Yes. But you can drop temp table if it exist